# MessageBox.Show issue

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog, messagebox

I have a lot of code like this and it usually works

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DialogResult result;
        result = MessageBox.Show( "Questa operazione potrebbe richiedere alcuni minuti,\r\nsei sicuro di voler continuare?", "Attenzione", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning );
        if ( result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes )
        {
            DoSomething();
        }
        else
        {
            DoSomethingElse();
        }
    }
    Catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogExceptio(ex);
    }
}
```

but for some reason on a specific `Windows Form` the `MessageBox` is not showing.
If I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it proceed like I have made a click on YES;
If I press the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key the MessageBox magically appear on the screen.

Any idea?
What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: update: in the `Form` I have a `DataGridView` and seems that the `MessageBox` issue append only if I have some colored row, that I color in `RowPrePaint` event.

Comment: Actually I've commented `DataRow.Cells["cell"].Value = false;` in my `DataGridView_RowPrePaint` and all is working as it have to.

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify owner for the message box (as far as I remember there should be overloaded method containing that argument). Owner should be current opened window.

Comment: I've tried setting the owner but nothing changed I still have the same issue. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by setting DataGrid.visible = false.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
    DialogResult result;
    DataGrid.visible=false;
    result = MessageBox.Show( "Questa operazione potrebbe richiedere alcuni minuti,\r\nsei sicuro di voler continuare?", "Attenzione", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning );
    if ( result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes )
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
    else
    {
        DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
DataGrid.visible=true;
Catch (Exception ex)
{
    LogExceptio(ex);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Of using some Threads in your application MessageBox May appear on background.
 So, You have to Pass MessageBox also in lambda expression Thread Like Below mentioned

```
new Thread(() => 
 {
    MessageBox.Show("Your Text");
 }).Start();
```

Hope It Will Help You...